# How to make a form on the backend?

Tags: 7, forms

I want to create a form for the backend in Drupal 7, something like the following:

```
label 1   text box 
label 2   text box 
label 3   text box 
label4    image
image
```

I then invoke the form output in the front page and other pages.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by creating a content type with fields, or using [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module. A lot depends on who will be filling out the form (anonymous visitors, content editors) and what you need to do with the results.

Comment: coud i set only the admin and the editor can fill out the form with webform?

Comment: Yes you can set which role can submit Webforms (globally or per form). If you need to control which roles can view Webforms, use one of the content access modules.

Comment: if i want to invoke the webform in the page--front.tpl.php. how do i do?

Comment: @enjoylife: @pushka's answer is correct, you can use a content type, a webform, or even a custom module (more work, but more flexible). Before you decide to go with Webform, make sure it is the best solution for your situation. What do you want to happen with the submitted information?

Comment: marcvangend ，i only invoke the form in page-front.tpl.php. in order to maintain it conveniently and make the editor changes the form content easily ,so i want to do a admin interface to the form. thank you. if i want to custom the module, how should i do?

Comment: @enjoylife: to invoke the form you use [drupal_get_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/drupal_get_form)